base safe migration to compatible base contract
I was wondering if there is an option to manually migrate a safe on base that was created before the new multi chain feature through an unsupported contract to create the same address as the original contract on Mainnet.
I currently get both these warnings when opening the safe through the webui, I can initiate transactions but it doesn't include the mentioned update to compatible contracts to the transaction.
Is there any way to manually initiate that update or to burn the current safe contract and recreate it through the new multi chain feature in order to get it fully functional and supported?
This Safe Account was created with an unsupported base contract. 
It is possible to migrate it to a compatible base contract. 
This migration will be automatically included with your first transaction.

This Safe Account was created with an unsupported base contract. 
The web interface might not work correctly. 
We recommend using the command line interface instead.

thank you

Hey Saferman, thanks for your question. Migration is not always possible. Could you kindly post the version of your Safe here, so we can investigate? If possible, you can just post the address of the Safe here (but not required, no worries!)
